# Redirect to a server after login from another server

Tags: php, curl

I have two server(say server1 and server2). There is a login panel on server1, if I login using server1 then I need to redirect to server2.

Here is the curl code I have:

```
Sample Curl request
curl -X POST -H "user_name: aaa" -H "auth_type: email" -H "app_key: someapikey" -H "platform: Android_MDA" -H "password: 123456" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d '' "here is server1 login url"
```

How can implement this using PHP.

```
Here is what I had done so far:
<?php

   $post_fields = '{"login": "aaa", "password": "123456"}';
   $cookie_file = tempnam('/temp', 'cookie');
   $ch = curl_init('here is server1 login url');

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_body);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
   curl_exec($ch);

 // Execute request and read response
 $response = curl_exec($ch);

 // Check errors
 if ($response) {
         echo $response . "\n";
 } else {
         $error = curl_error($ch). '(' .curl_errno($ch). ')';
         echo $error . "\n";
 }

 // Close connection
 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```

Response I get:
Failed to connect to server1(i.e the url Iam using): Connection timed out(7)

Answer (score 0):

1. $post_body is not defined.
2. you are using cookie_file however in you working curl case there is no cookies being sent. so at list remove cookies related like for  a trail.

Comment: still same response @enRaiser

Comment: can you update the code again. with above changes. so that at list someone else can start fresh.